# How to draw an equation in an irregular ImplicitRegion？

Tags: plotting, graphics

I am trying to draw an equation in an specific area. I use `ImplicitRegion` to define the area. I can use `RegionPlot` to draw the ImplicitRegion, but I can't draw an equation in it with `ContourPlot`, even with the simple equation "r==1/2". However, I can draw the equation in the regular area like Rectangle. Does anyone have advice for this?

```
ClearAll[r, b, equ, ans`vt, ans`vs, equal, line1, line2, region];


(*Calculation*)
equ = 2/3*v^2 + (1 - r)*v - 1;

ans`vt = v /. Solve[equ == 0, v];
ans`vt = ans`vt[[2]];


equ = (1 - b)*v^2 + (1 - b)*v + 3*r*ans`vt^2 - 2*ans`vt^3 - b;

ans`vs = v /. Solve[equ == 0, v];
ans`vs = ans`vs[[2]];

equal = b /. Solve[ans`vs - ans`vt == 0, b];

line1 = 2/3 - 2/3*ans`vt^3 + r*ans`vt^2;
line2 = equal;

(*Draw*)

region = ImplicitRegion[
   b - line2 >= 0 && b - line1 <= 0 && b >= 0 && b <= 1 && r >= 0 && 
    r <= 2/3, {r, b}];

RegionPlot[region]

ContourPlot[r == 1/2, {r, b} \[Element] region]

ContourPlot[r == 1/2, {r, b} \[Element] Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2/3, 2/3}]]
```

Comment: …``equal = b /. Solve[ans`vs - ans`vt == 0, b]`` should be ``equal = b /. Solve[ans`vs - ans`vt == 0, b][[1]]``. Your original code has lead to something similar to `{2} > 0`.

Comment: What's really surprising here is, `RegionPlot` tolerates the wrong input.